# Cargar arraylist de datos en jtable

Tags: java, arraylist

Hola necesito saber cómo puedo cargar un arraylist de Departamento definido en un paquete en una clase llamada Facultad, en un jtable que se encuentra en otro paquete. Cargarlo no mediante un botón sino al abrir el jframe cargue los datos y los muestre

O sea mas explicado existe una faultad que contiene el arraylist de varios departamentos, cree algunos departamentos en la clase principal por lo que necesito que dichos departamentos me aparezcan en la interfaz inmediatamente al darle play al programa. Saludos y gracias de antemano.

```
package Logic;

public class Departamento {
    private String nombre;
    private String nombreJefe;
    public Departamento(String nombre, String nombreJefe) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.nombreJefe = nombreJefe;
    }
    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }
    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }
    public String getNombreJefe() {
        return nombreJefe;
    }
    public void setNombreJefe(String nombreJefe) {
        this.nombreJefe = nombreJefe;
    }
    
}
```

```
package Logic;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Facultad {
    private String nombre;
    private int anioCreada;
    private ArrayList<Departamento> depar;
    
    public Facultad(String nombre, int anioCreada) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.anioCreada = anioCreada;
        depar=new ArrayList<Departamento>();
    }

    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }

    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

    public int getAnioCreada() {
        return anioCreada;
    }

    public void setAnioCreada(int anioCreada) {
        this.anioCreada = anioCreada;
    }
    
    public ArrayList<Departamento> getDepar() {
        return depar;
    }

    public void setDepar(ArrayList<Departamento> depar) {
        this.depar = depar;
    }

    public void imprimirDepart() {
        for(Departamento d: depar)
            System.out.println(d.getNombre()+" "+d.getNombreJefe());
    }
    
}
```

```
package Logic;

public class Principal {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Facultad fac=new Facultad("Informatica",1954);
        fac.getDepar().add(new Departamento("Humanidades","Jose Leyva"));
        fac.getDepar().add(new Departamento("Investigaciones","Josue Sainz"));
        fac.getDepar().add(new Departamento("Comunicaciones","Ernest Garcia"));
        fac.getDepar().add(new Departamento("Logistica","Ana Sanz"));
        fac.getDepar().add(new Departamento("PM","Jose Leyva"));
        fac.imprimirDepart();
    }

}
```

```
package gui;
import Logic.Departamento;
import Logic.Facultad;
import Logic.Principal;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

public class tablaDepartamento extends JFrame {
    private Facultad facultad;
    private JPanel contentPane;
    private JTable table;

    String columnas[]= {"Nombre","Jefe"};
    boolean columnasEditables[]= {false,false};
    DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel() {
        public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int col) {
            return columnasEditables[col];
        }       
    };
    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    tablaDepartamento frame = new tablaDepartamento();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */
    public tablaDepartamento() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        contentPane.setLayout(null);
        
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
        scrollPane.setBounds(10, 29, 394, 221);
        contentPane.add(scrollPane);
        
        //No estoy segura de lo de abajo
        ArrayList<Departamento> depar = facultad.getDepar();
for (Departamento depart : depar) {
    Object[] fila = new Object[depar.size()];
    fila[0] = depart.getNombre();
    fila[1] = depart.getNombreJefe();

    model.addRow(fila);
}

        table = new JTable();
        table.setModel(new DefaultTableModel());
        model.setColumnIdentifiers(columnas);
        scrollPane.setViewportView(table);

    
    }   
}
```

Comment: Buenas tardes Lizzy, necesitamos código para poder ayudarte. Saludos!

Comment: Hola, ya lo edite y puse el codigo. Ojala pueda ayudarme. Sl2

Answer (score 0):

te faltó pasarle el model a la jTable

```
 table.setModel(new DefaultTableModel());
```

ese código lo que hace es crear la tabla con un modelo de datos vacía, debes pasarle los datos al jTable así:

```
 table.setModel(model);
```

así puedes solucionar el problema
Saludos!